# My program is throwing an exception trying to delete an element from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a linked list and two functions - one to add and other to delete members from the list.
When I try to delete a member I am getting an exception in the delete function.

The exception is in line

```
if (strcmp((temp_person_ptr->name), name_to_remove))
```

The exception says -> Unhandled exception at 0x50C4EF18 (ucrtbased.dll) in singly_linked_list.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred

Full program is below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "globals.h"

extern struct person* starting_address;

struct person* delete_person(size_t* list_size_ptr, struct person* ptr_current_person)
{
    printf("There are %u items in list \n", *list_size_ptr);

    struct person* temp_person_ptr = starting_address, *to_save_person_ptr;
    printf("The items in list are \n");
    while (temp_person_ptr)
    {
        printf("%s \n", temp_person_ptr->name);
        temp_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr->next_person_ptr;
    }

    char name_to_remove[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    printf("Please enter the name to remove \n");
    gets_s(name_to_remove, MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 1);

    temp_person_ptr = starting_address;
    to_save_person_ptr = starting_address; // Not required by logic - just to initialize for compiler
    while (temp_person_ptr)
    {
        if (strcmp((temp_person_ptr->name), name_to_remove))
        {
            to_save_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr;
            temp_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr->next_person_ptr;
        }
        else
        {
            // Since we are going to remove temp_person_ptr - we save it's next person_ptr in preceding person which is to_save_person_ptr
            // Only if the person_ptr to be removed is NOT the first person
            // For now - assume - one element name will match
            if (temp_person_ptr != starting_address)
                to_save_person_ptr->next_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr->next_person_ptr; // takes care if temp_person_ptr is the last one as well
            else // Else the next person's address is the new starting address
                starting_address = temp_person_ptr->next_person_ptr;

            free(temp_person_ptr);
            (*list_size_ptr)--;
        }
    }
    return (ptr_current_person);
}
```

The part to add an element to the list looks as below (entire function) -

```
struct person* add_person(size_t* list_size_ptr, struct person* ptr_current_person)
{

    struct person *ptr_new_person;

    ptr_new_person = (struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    // If first person- its starting address is the starting address of list
    if ((*list_size_ptr) == 0)
    {
        starting_address = ptr_new_person;
    }
    else
    {
        //1. Add the new address to the chain - only if this is not the first person
        ptr_current_person->next_person_ptr = ptr_new_person;
    }
    ptr_new_person->next_person_ptr = NULL;

    printf("Please enter the name \n");
    gets_s(ptr_new_person->name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 1);

    // 2. We may make ptr_new_person as ptr_current_person
    ptr_current_person = ptr_new_person;
    // 3. Now onwards ptr_current_person refers to the pointer to the newly added person

    (*list_size_ptr)++;
    return (ptr_current_person);
}
```

Comment: You probably don't have `NULL` as the `next_person_ptr` in the last element of the list. Check your code that creates new list elements.

Comment: Hi Barmar. I checked, its there.I added the code snippet  to the question.

Comment: Is the `person.name` a pointer or an array? If it's a pointer, it's apparently invalid.

Comment: person.name is a char array -   char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

Comment: Another possibility is that it's uninitialized or missing its null terminator.

Comment: You should be able to investigate all the possibilities in a debugger.

Comment: When it gets the error, check the value of `temp_person_ptr` to see if it's valid, and print the contents of `temp_person_ptr->name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (temp_person_ptr)
{
    if (strcmp((temp_person_ptr->name), name_to_remove))
    {
        to_save_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr;
        temp_person_ptr = temp_person_ptr->next_person_ptr;
    }
    else{...}
```

From this snippet it looks like temp_person_ptr is pointing to something, but the ->name is NULL.  Add a printf statement like this before your strcmp:

```
if(!(temp_person_ptr->name)){
      printf("This is why your segfaulting\n");
    }
```

And you will either see that ->name is null or its something else.  good luck

Comment: He says `name` is an array, so it can't be null.

Comment: I checked. The message did not get printed - so its not entering the if, but the exception occured.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted enough to get a proper analysis and help.  The guidance for making a complete, minimal example isn't just for grins; often by reducing a problem to its core, the programmer finds their error themselves.  If not, it gives a great place for other to.   Regardless, the loop in your delete is essentially:

```
temp = start;
while (temp) {
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name)) {
         temp = temp->next;
    } else {
         free(temp);
    }
}
```

Your free should likely have been something like:

```
void *p = temp->next;
free(temp);
temp = p;
```

Comment: I think I am doing it - using to_save_person_ptr. It is getting the address of the element before temp and once match is found - it writes the contents of temp-> next into to_save_person_ptr-> next, then does the free

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I was not exiting the while loop after free and going on all the way. 
I added a return to return after free is done and list size is decremented. It works now.